# ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd

Tags: python, pandas

I used pandas to read excel file and then received an ImportError shown below.

code:

```
pressure_2018=pd.read_excel('2018_pressures.xlsx')
```

Error:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

Then I installed xlrd on my computer using code shown below:

```
pip install xlrd
```

But I still received the same issue. In output, it always returned this ImportError. It made me feel confused and frustrated, because I have installed xlrd on my computer.
Could you please give me some ideas about how to resolve this error.

Comment: _Probably_ the `pip` you ran is connected to a different Python version than the one which is running your script. We need to see significantly more details to troubleshoot this. Missing alignment between Python versions is a common problem but there's dozens of different ways you could end up in that situation. Which OS, how did you install Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) using `pip install openpyxl` and then try:

```
pd.read_excel('2018_pressures.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

This is an alternative solution but it will work.

Comment: I have encountered an error : ```zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file```. And openpyxl is installed through the anaconda.

Answer (score 4):

I share with you my experience on this !

1. step check whether you have the following excel packages installed: openpyxl, odf, xlrd

to check:
`pip list` or `conda list`

2. If there is no installation package reading the excel file, then install one of them with this method:

   pip install xlrd, pip install openpyxl, pip install odf or pip install pyxslb

for conda : `conda install xlrd, conda install openpyxl, conda install odf, conda install pyxslb` 
then check again whether your file reads correctly:

```
dataFrame = pd. read_excel('C:/.../.xlsx', engine= 'openpyxl')
```

if it gives an error again, it means that you are using another interpreter to read the code if you want to read it in https://www.kaggle.com/abdumaleek/kasco-tasks/editkaggle or in collaboration, then you need to install the package for reading exel file again

for example, in kaggle :
`!pip install openpyxl`

```
import openpyxl
df = pd. read_excel('C:/.../.xlsx', engine= 'openpyxl')
```

this is 100% should work
support with a like

Answer (score 2):

I'm in Windows 10. I downloaded all of Anaconda on 1 computer and just the Spyder part on a different computer from Anaconda web site. The computer with all of Anaconda on it did not get this error; the computer with just Spyder on it got this error of not being able to find xlrd when doing the following

```
import pandas as pd

import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https:a internet file name in here that is an xlsx file", "sample.xlsx")

df = pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx")

df
```

Answer (score 0):

After installation, you need to restart your Python environment